# How to validate a token in Django Knox Authentication

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication, django-rest-knox

I am using knox authentication to login user after validating otp using the view below

```
class LoginPhoneApi(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self,request,formt=None):
        serializer = LoginwithPhoneSerializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request,user,backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
        userid = user.id
        username = user.username
        fullname= user.full_name
        temp_list=super().post(request, format=None)

        temp_list.data["userid"]=userid
        temp_list.data["username"]=username
        temp_list.data["fullname"]=fullname
        print(temp_list.data["token"])
        return Response({"data":temp_list.data})
```

I am able to login and get the authentication token.
Now one of my view requires authenticated users.
How do I validate this token which is in the header of the url request.

I am able to fetch the token. How do I use this token to validate and login the user.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])

        auth_method, token = self.request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ', 1)
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You need to use `knox.auth.TokenAuthentication` in your authentication classes. Can you confirm that you have this?

Comment: thank you for the prompt response. And no I don;'t have it, could you please be and share an example of how I can.

Comment: I answered it from your question [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68296177/6759844)