# Django TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quiz_name'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I am trying to access a url from flutter webview , however, I am getting the following error.
When I try to access this directly, I dont see any error.

```
File "/home/quiz/views.py", line 629, in dispatch
    return super(QuizTakeAutoAuth, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quiz_name'
```

views.py

```
class QuizTakeAutoAuth(APIView):

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

   
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'foo': 'bar'
        }
        
        return Response(content)

   
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])

        if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
            raise PermissionDenied

        if self.sitting is False:
            print("sitting false")
            if self.logged_in_user:
                return render(request, self.single_complete_template_name)
            else:                    
                redirecturl = "/login/?next=/quiz/"+self.kwargs['quiz_name']+"/startquiz/"
                return redirect(redirecturl)   

        return super(QuizTakeAutoAuth, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<quiz_name>[\w-]+)/startquiz/$',view=QuizTakeAutoAuth.as_view(), name='quiz_question_auth'),
```

What am I missing here? I am using the same view elsewhere without any knox Tokenauthentication and works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a `paramater` `quiz_name` in the `url`, it is being passed to your corresponding view. The current signature of your `get` method doesn't accept any additional parameters.

You may fix this by changing the method signature to:

```py
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    quiz_name = kwargs.get('quiz_name')
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. However, I have a follow up question. Will it be possible to help me in a freelance mode?